# Index and length must refer to a location in the string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring

I am dynamically building a table in C# and I am pulling values from a database and I am getting the index and length must refer to a location in the string exception.

Here is the line of code that is getting kicked out at:

```
cl.Text = totalMarginMonth.ToString().Substring(0,5);
```

totalMarginMonth is equal to 41.3 and is a decimal type when i get the error.  I understand that the length of the string is not 5 but most of the values have at least a length of five.  Am I going to have to put an if statement to read the length of the string that is getting passed in before I substring it?

Comment: What... exactly is the point of truncating the string length to 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just clamp the second value to substring instead.

```
int len = Math.Min(totalMarginMonth.ToString().Length, 5);
c1.Text = totalMarginMonth.ToString().Substring(0, len);
```

Comment: I should have stated that totalMarginMonth is a decimal and therefore you cannot call length on a decimal

Comment: that's fine, just call ToString() twice. updated the answer

Comment: Awesome! this worked, i had tried something similar but i hadnt tried saving it to an int before

Answer (score 1):

Write an extension method that you can use everywhere:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
  public static string Truncate( this string s , int maxLength )
  {
    if ( s == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    if ( maxLength < 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxLength");

    return s.Length <= maxLength ? s : s.Substring(0,maxLength);
  }
}
```

Then its a simple matter of:

```
string text = totalMarginMonth.ToString().Truncate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you pass the length in as a second value in your substring?

```
c1.Text = totalMarginMonth
          .ToString()
          .Substring( 0, Math.Min( totalMarginMonth.ToString().Length , 5 )
          );
```